# ImportError: No module named 'pyspark.errors' when importing DeltaTable in AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook (Docker Container)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pyspark, aws-glue

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering a challenging issue when trying to ***import DeltaTable from the delta.tables*** module in my Jupyter Notebook.

I'm running AWS Glue locally on my MacBook using a ***Docker container*** with the image.

***amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01***

The error message I'm facing is:

```
An error was encountered:
No module named 'pyspark.errors'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glue_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/delta/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from delta.tables import DeltaTable
  File "/home/glue_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/delta/tables.py", line 21, in <module>
    import delta.exceptions  # noqa: F401; pylint: disable=unused-variable
  File "/home/glue_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/delta/exceptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyspark.errors.exceptions import captured
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.errors'
```

Here are the key details:

1. I've installed the delta library using the command pip install
   delta-spark.
2. pyspark Version 3.3.0+amzn.1.dev0 traced using `print(pyspark.__version__)`
3. Python Version 3.10.2
4. delta-spark-3.0.0 py4j-0.10.9.7
5. The line of code causing the error is:

`from delta.tables import DeltaTable`

It appears there may be a compatibility issue or a missing dependency in my Jupyter Notebook environment within the AWS Glue Docker container. Despite installing the necessary libraries, the error persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, solutions, or guidance to resolve this issue and successfully import **DeltaTable** within my AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook environment.

Even below code throws same error:

```
import delta
print(delta.__version__)
```

Please feel free to request any additional information you might need.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue and JUST found this answer that worked for me:

[stackoverflow question 59373463](https://As%20the%20correct%20answer%20is%20hidden%20in%20the%20comments%20of%20the%20accepted%20solution,%20I%20thought%20I%27d%20add%20it%20here.%20%20You%20need%20to%20create%20your%20spark%20context%20with%20some%20extra%20settings%20and%20then%20you%20can%20import%20delta:%20%20spark_session%20=%20SparkSession.builder%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20.master(%22local%22)%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20.config(%22spark.jars.packages%22,%20%22io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0%22)%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20.config(%22spark.sql.extensions%22,%20%22io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension%22)%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20.config(%22spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog%22,%20%22org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog%22)%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20.getOrCreate()%20%20from%20delta.tables%20import%20*%20Annoyingly,%20your%20IDE%20will%20of%20course%20shout%20at%20you%20about%20this%20as%20the%20package%20isn%27t%20installed%20and%20you%20will%20also%20be%20operating%20without%20autocomplete%20and%20type%20hints.%20I%27m%20sure%20there%27s%20a%20work%20around%20and%20I%20will%20update%20if%20I%20come%20accross%20it.%20%20The%20package%20itself%20is%20on%20their%20github%20here%20and%20the%20readme%20suggests%20you%20can%20pip%20install%20but%20that%20doesn%27t%20work.%20In%20theory%20you%20could%20clone%20it%20and%20install%20manually.)

---

As the correct answer is hidden in the comments of the accepted solution, I thought I'd add it here.

You need to create your spark context with some extra settings and then you can import delta:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

from delta.tables import *
```

Annoyingly, your IDE will of course shout at you about this as the package isn't installed and you will also be operating without autocomplete and type hints. I'm sure there's a work around and I will update if I come accross it.

The package itself is on their github here and the readme suggests you can pip install but that doesn't work. In theory you could clone it and install manually.

---

I can't take credit for the answer above, I just found it, tried it and it worked!